brightway25 and importing local copy of ecoinvent v3.10
I know we now have ecoinvent_interface to directly download from Ecoinvent API but I have a local copy of ecoinvent v3.10 and have no internet access in the system. How do I use brightway25 in this case to import ecoinvent v3.10? I get 60 something unlinked exchanges if I try "ei.statistics()"

try this function from https://github.com/Haitham-ghaida/Premise_BW_recipes/blob/main/lca_recipes.ipynb
I would recommend you put in a new project name to avoid issues.
import bw2data as bd
import bw2io as bi
# from premise_gwp import add_premise_gwp  # only add if you want to use the premise

def base_setup_with_ecoinvent(
    project_name: str,
    db_name: str,
    db_loc: str,
    reparametrize_lognormals: bool = False,
    # setup_premise_gwp: bool = True, # only add if you want to use the premise
):
    """
    This method sets up a Brightway project with the ecoinvent database.

    Parameters
    ----------
    db_name : str
        The name of the database to import
    db_loc : str
        The location of the database to import (e.g. "C:/Users/.../ecoinvent 3.7.1_cutoff_ecoSpold02/datasets"))
    reparametrize_lognormals : bool, optional
        Whether or not to reparametrize lognormal distributions, by default True (recommended)
        This sets the mean of the lognormal distribution to static value of the LCA calculation.
        This is recommended because the default behavior of Brightway is to set the mean of the lognormal distribution to the value of the LCA calculation.
        This can lead to problems when performing Monte Carlo LCA calculations, because the mean of the lognormal distribution will change with each iteration.
        This can lead to a large number of iterations being required to reach convergence.
    setup_premise_gwp : bool, optional
        Whether or not to setup the premise_gwp method, by default True
        This method provides characterization factors for biogenic CO2 flows and hydrogen emissions to air.
    """

    # set the project, it will create a new project if it does not exist
    bd.projects.set_current(project_name)

    # imports biosphere flows, it will skip if already done
    bi.bw2setup()

    # get the path to the datasets folder
    db_dir = db_loc
    # give a name to the database
    data_base_name = db_name
    # check if the database is already in the project, and skip if yes
    if data_base_name in bd.databases:
        print("Database has already been imported")

    else:
        # import database
        db = bi.SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(
            db_dir,
            data_base_name,
            reparametrize_lognormals=reparametrize_lognormals,
        )

        db.apply_strategies()

        db.statistics()

        # db.drop_unlinked(True)
        # writes database into sql
        db.write_database()
        # Because some of the scenarios can yield LCI databases
        # containing net negative emission technologies (NET),
        # it is advised to account for biogenic CO2 flows when calculating
        # Global Warming potential indicators.
        # `premise_gwp` provides characterization factors for such flows.
        # It also provides factors for hydrogen emissions to air.
        # if setup_premise_gwp: # only add if you want to use the premise
        #     add_premise_gwp()


Use it like:
base_setup_with_ecoinvent('newProject', 'nameOfDataBase', 'full/path/to/your/db/where/you/saved/it')
Note when you download ecoinvent it is compressed so unzip it and the path should point to the datasets folder something like "C:/Users/.../ecoinvent 3.7.1_cutoff_ecoSpold02/datasets"
